# Can I make Plank take the full length available

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, plank

I just installed Plank on my Xubuntu. I would like Plank to take the full-length available (even though I've only got a few icons).

I can't find a setting for this in the preferences. Is it something you can achieve by configuring the theme in use?

In my case I have Plank configured to the left, so I would want it to take the full height of the screen available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Right-Click of the mouse on the Plank bar and choose Preferences.  Then in the Appearance tab set Alignment to Fill.  That should make Plank use the entire length of the screen.

[image]

Hope this helps!